# SharePoint Framework without command line

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-tooling

Is it possible to build SharePoint Framework Web Parts without using NodeJS, Yeoman, gulp?

Answer (score 2):

The three components included in the Microsoft SPFx framework are npm (the package manager), Yeoman (the scaffolding tool), and Gulp (the build system). You could ostensibly do manually what each of these tools automates for you, but it would be quite difficult. I understand there is some support for alternatives coming (e.g. Yarn instead of Gulp).

Comment: I understand that it might be difficult, the question was whether it is possible at all. If it is possible, how can it be done? Can it be done by using AddOn or nugets for Visual Studio instead rely on the command line of NodeJs?